# Laucher icon generated from Android Asset Studio is small

Tags: android, material-design, android-icons

I generated a text app icon using [Roman Nurik's Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html) but the size seems to be small compared to the icons installed on my phone. I placed all the icons for all densities but it doesn't work.

[image]

The icon (hdpi)
[image]

Comment: Did you put them in drawable or mipmap folder?

Comment: When you generated the icon what percentage was the padding?

Comment: post the icons to have a look

Comment: I already tried using mipmap and drawable. The padding is 0. I added the icon for hdpi.

Comment: no dont worry posting, just tried it and it adds padding even if its 0 or -15. solution is to try another online service to create your icon as i dont see see an option there to fill the whole container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the online service you are using is not utilizing the space to fit the icon completely as you can see from the squares around the icon so they look smaller.

I dont see an option there to fix that,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. [Roman Nurik's tool](https://github.com/romannurik/AndroidAssetStudio) is awesome, but the icon generated with it was small compared to others in my phone.

The solution i found was to clone his [repository](https://github.com/romannurik/AndroidAssetStudio). Modify one line of code and run it locally. It's pretty simple: Just go to app/scripts/pages/LauncherIconGenerator.js and find the following line:

```
square: { x:  5, y:  5, w:  38, h:  38 },
```

Change it to look like:

```
square: { x:  2, y:  2, w:  44, h:  44 },
```

And then the icon will be bigger.

Not sure if it breaks with the Material Design guidelines, but solves the problem in the question.

For a more detailed discussion about it, you can check [this issue](https://github.com/romannurik/AndroidAssetStudio/issues/73).

Comment: Pls how do I run it locally after cloning it?

Comment: @clementiano it's a node app, so you will need to install node and npm in order to run it locally. After that just type `npm install` and then `gulp serve`. BTW: instructions are in the [repository](https://github.com/romannurik/AndroidAssetStudio) also

Answer (score 1):

put all your launcher icons in mipmap folders as new guide line of android developer site.

there is built in assets studio provided by Android Studio.
you can create launcher icons with different resolutions by just one click. no extra plugin needed.

just right click on project go to New > Image Assets

[image]

It provides built in Vector assets support In Vector Assets Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and ended up using [Roman Nurik's Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=607d8b%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&backColor=ffffff%2C100&effects=none) to create my app icon, and than put the web_hi_res_512.png in the built in Image Assets tool which @ErShani mentioned. If you set the padding to -10% it should work fine.